# Phonegap application not scaling images properly on Android 2.1

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, image-scaling

We have developed an application using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap which works flawlessly on iOS devices.  It's now time to port the app to the Android OS, which in most cases works great, except when the app is run on a device running Android 2.1.

Images are not scaled properly in this case (they are much larger than they should be).  It is likely that I am seeing an example of this bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5141

There is a work-around posted in the linked forum, but it does not seem to have any effect in my case.

If anybody has further suggestions they would be welcomed!

Comment: What's your meta tag view port in html ?

Comment: Have you tried using either Sencha Profiles or actually using a switch statement to check the device window width and accordingly setting the image ?